# Torsional rigidity of a composite shaft in parallel

Tags: solid-mechanics, strength

Consider the following composite shaft which consists of 3 different materials with modulus of rigidity of $G_1$, $G_2$ and $G_3$. Shaft 1 has length 2L, and shafts 2 and 3, L. Assume they are all 'glued' together.

[image]

Knowing that the left-half of shaft 1 is connected in parallel to shaft 2 (and one could say something similar to the right-half and shaft 3), I would like to prove that the torsional rigidity $(GJ)$ of each side of the composite shaft is given by

$$(GJ)_{\text{left}} = G_1 J_1 + G_2 J_2 \qquad (GJ)_{\text{right}} = G_1 J_1 + G_3 J_3$$

I just assume that this is correct based on how we find the equivalent spring constant of wo parallel ones, and that, in this case, GJ is kind of a torsional spring constant.

Comment: This looks like a homework question, and to get help here you need to show your work or analysis so far. People will help by correcting and hinting but not by just doing all the work.

Comment: This is not a homework. I am studying by myself for an entrance examination of a university. Also, proving the relation above is not part of the problem (finding the twist angle at the middle is). I just want to understand why this relation holds, maybe by some insight, not the entire solution. For instance, where to start; where to look for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expression is correct, the proof is carried out below for the left segment of the composite bars:

From static force equilibrium, we have

$T = T_1 + T_2$ ----- (1)

Furthermore, the angle of twist $\phi$ must be the same for both parts,

$\phi = \dfrac{T_1L}{G_1J_1} = \dfrac{T-2L}{G_2J_2}$ ----- (2)

From (2),

$T_1 = T\dfrac{G_1J_1}{G_1J_1 + G_2J_2}$ ----- (3a), and

$T_2 = T\dfrac{G_2J_2}{G_1J_1 + G_2J_2}$ ----- (3b)

Substitute eqs (3a) and (3b) into (2), and we get

$\phi = \dfrac{TL}{G_1J_1 + G_2J_2} = \dfrac{TL}{(GJ)_{composite}}$

[image]

Comment: Thank you @r13, I will try to prove it again. So the "trick" here is to know that both inner and outer shafts share the section's torque $(T = T_1 + T_2)$ and that the twist angle must be the same (as they are glued) for both shafts.

Comment: Correct. If they are not bonded together, they will act independently depending on how the torque is applied. Now, since they are bonded by adhesive, then they must satisfy both the force equilibrium and strain compatibility to be fully composite.

Comment: two more questions if you may. $T$ in this case is the **internal torque** of the section that contains materials 1 and 2, correct? Also, in the final expression, we are just stating that the deflection of the composite shaft under torque $T$ shall be equal to the deflection of shaft 1 (could be 2) under torque $T_1$ (could be $T_2$).

Comment: Let me know if the added figure does not answer your question.

Comment: This figure was really helpful! I tried some problems with this in mind and they made a lot more sense. Thanks for the visual intuition, I usually learn better this way.